# jQuery: Can't find button identified by class and data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

**jQuery**

```
console.log($("button[class='confirm_button'][data-id='5141']").length);
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs confirm_button" data-id="5141">Click to confirm</button>
```

The `console.log` is triggered on a click of the button. However, I always get a length of zero. I tried hiding/showing it but it was failing so went to see if it existed and got a value of zero for the length.

Anything obvious?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the `data-id` attribute alone?

Comment: In the table row, there are elements which share the same data-id

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `console.log($("button[class$='confirm_button'][data-id='5141']").length);` which checks if class ends with given string

Comment: When I tried this on inputs and textareas, I didn't need to add the $ but this seems to work for the buttons. Any idea why?

Comment: it is match the end of class attribute. In this case it checks whether the attribute ends with `confirm_button`

Comment: you replace `$` with `*` whcih means `contains`, `^` whcih means `starts with`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use Attribute Contains Word Selector **'~'**  instead of Attribute Equals Selector **'='**

**Issue:** using class with '=' should match exact class - **'btn btn-warning btn-xs confirm_button'**

As per official jQuery documentation ,

**Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]**
Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log($("button[class~='confirm_button'][data-id='5141']").length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs confirm_button" data-id="5141">Click to confirm</button>
```

Please find all the attribute type options - https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/agmzKj?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

The selector

```
$("button[class='confirm_button'][data-id='5141']")
```

is searching for an element with `button` tag, that has an attribute `class` that is equal to `confirm_button` and another attribute `data-id` with value `5141`.

This selector is not selecting the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs confirm_button" data-id="5141">Click to confirm</button>
```

because this button does not have an attribute `class` with value `confirm_button` but instead has an attribute `class` with value `btn btn-warning btn-xs confirm_button`.

If you want to select a button with a specific class, you could use the selector:

```
$("button.confirm_button[data-id='5141']")
```